# Not able to remote into Windows azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

When I click on connect button in Azure Portal, the RDP file is opened and it asks for credential,. not sure what credentials to give. Is it my login to azure portal or something else?

The RDP login prompt shows "MicrsoftAccount\PortalLoginUserName" as user name.What should be typed in password? Is it the portal password? If i try that it does not work.

When creating VM i have provided new username and new password is that what i need to use? if this what i need to use what would be domain?

Answer (score 15):

You need to use the username and password you used when provisioning the VM. These credentials are not the same as your Azure account credentials. And every VM may have its own unique credentials.

When entering your username in the RDP client, either enter `\username` or `localhost\username`.

Comment: localhost\username worked for me where as \username didn't. Thanks!